# Meaning of in strictly military terms

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> So even if Gettysburg was less than decisive ***in strictly military terms***, it was decisive enough to restore the sinking morale of the union.

What does in strictly military terms mean? I am at a loss to make sense of it. Also can I replace in strictly military terms with in a strictly military sense? Would they both mean the same? If not, the please tell me the difference between them.

Comment: **union** was probably capitalized as a proper noun in the (uncited) original.  The Union refers to the northern states, as distinct from the secessionist South.  The Union's sinking morale was restored by the outcome at Gettysburg, even though it was not a decisive military victory.

Answer (score 1):

'in strictly military terms' means in the context or in the *viewpoint* of the military. So, while Gettysburg did not achieve an obvious battle victory (the military terms) it succeeded nevertheless in instilling a measure of confidence in the troops (non-military terms).
Yes, you can use either military terms or military sense, they are almost identical.

Comment: "In military terms" does not refer narrowly to the opinion held at that time by the Army or by the armies, if that is what you mean by "in the viewpoint of *the* military".